# Meaning of 譲れん (譲れない)

Tags: meaning

Trying to figure out what 譲れない equates to in English. Context is that this is from a manga, and the conversation is:

> Character 1: はぁ、相変わらず熱心だなァ。
>
> Character 2: 無論、僕は庭師だからな。庭だけは**譲れん**。お前も料理に関しては**譲れん**だろう？それと同じだ。

I'm under the impression that 譲れない means "non-negotiable". However, if I were to use that meaning, in English the above sentence would be something like:

> Of course, I'm a gardener after all. Gardening is the one thing I don't negotiate on. You also don't negotiate when it comes to cooking, do you? It's the same as that.

But I feel like I'm missing another meaning for 譲れない as "non-negotiable" in this context doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: I think you're right on, but a better definition would probably be "concede" or "yield".

Comment: What is the manga?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you have to do a verb-for-a-verb type of translation, you might consider using phrases such as:

> "I'm the boss/rulebook (when it comes to ~~)."
>
> "I'm second to none (in ~~)"

because that is the nuance of 「[譲]{ゆず}れない」 in this context.

Comment: 「無双」っていう感じですか？？

Answer (score 3):

譲れん is a kind of local dialect of 譲れない, which is prominent in the western part of Japan. As a Kyūshū-ite, I used to use れん, せん, and ん like いけん in boyhood instead of いけない daily and as a matter of course.

…れん instead of …れない is used in similar way as …せん instead of …せない

> 眠れない→眠れん - Can't sleep.
>
> 食べられない→食べれん - Can't eat.
>
> 喋らない→喋れん - Can't speak.
>
> 教えることができない→教えれん - Can't teach.

もう、やってはおられない→もう、やっちゃおれん - It's hopeless.

> 話せない→話せん - Can't speak.
>
> 通せない→通せん - I won't let you pass.
>
> 崩せない→崩せん - Can't break.

Kenkyusha’s New Japanese English Dictionary (新和英中辞典) gives definitions of 譲る as:

1. give, hand over, transfer.
2. abdicate the throne (in favor of one’s son).
3. give up one’s seat to sb.
4. leave one’s post to make way for a (younger person)
5. give way to, concede

I think your example of the gardener’s remark in your question, "僕は庭師だからな。庭だけは譲れん" meaning "I’m a professional gardener (the gardening is my turf), I cannot give my throne (seat) to you (junior)" comes under 3. or 4. of the above definitions rather than your take – “non negotiable.”

>

Comment: この場合「（庭に関しては）譲歩できない」って意味ではないでしょうか・・・？　３・４番でなく５番の・・・。(３番は「人に座席を譲る」ですし、４番は「後進に地位を譲る」ですし・・・)

Comment: I’m not able to give a conclusive comment on the interpretation of 譲れん used here without the knowledge of full passage covering the cited part. But I took this way from the given piece of words. ‘Give up one’s seat to sb.’ is a figurative expression, and not always limited to ‘offering the seat to the senior in the bus and train.’ It can be used to mean withdrawing from one’s position in favor of the other. 
If you take 「（庭に関しては）譲歩できない」for 譲れん, I would put it as “(as far as the gardening,) I wouldn’t compromise (with you),” rather than “It’s non-negotiable.”

Answer (score -2):

I'd say it's "leave (it) to others" in this case

Comment: I don't think this any bad answer. I'm surprised to find you guys like to down-vote other's post so easily and rashly.

Comment: ^ でも、「(～に関して)譲歩する/妥協する/concede/compromise」と「(～を)人任せにする/leave to others」とでは、かなり違いますし・・・